# Trying to check user against database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Hello I am trying to check the username and password of a user after they have submitted a login form to check if they exist on the database using PDO but it returns false.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
//import all of the available functions
require_once('func/functions.php');

//create a connection to the database
$database = new database('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
$database->connect();
$database->select('mjbox');

//Check if the user is logged in
loggedin();


//Check if the submit button has been clicked first
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    //Check if user exists on database
    match_login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
}
?>

//Check if user is logged in
function loggedin(){
    //Check if the loggedin status is set to true, meaning that user is logged in.
    if ( isset ( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true  ) {
        echo '<p>Hello '. $_SESSION['username'] . ', <a href="Logout.php">Logout.</a></p>';
    }else{
        //If the user is not logged in display a login form
        echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="username">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="password">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">';
        echo '<form>';
    }

}

//Check users login details
function match_login($username, $password){
        //If the button has been clicked get the variables
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mjbox","root", "usbw");
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox WHERE username=':name' AND password=':pword'");
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pword", $_POST['password']);
        $stmt->execute();

        if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){

            echo 'There is a match!';
        }else{
            echo 'nooooo';
        }
}
```

This is the first time I've attempted to use PDO, have I used it correctly? All the details appear to be correct and the user exists within the database so can't undertand why it doesn't return true.
Thanks

Comment: [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) doesn't necessarily return the value you want, you should `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead and use `PDOStatement::fetchColumn` to get the result, like the documentation for `rowCount` advises you to do. Some other issues: Use `<input type="password"` for password fields. Don't store passwords in plaintext. Don't ignore the arguments you pass to the `match_login` function.

Answer (score 1):

Binding a string in PDO automatically adds quotes for you. Just remove the quotes around :name and :pword in the query and that should fix it.